# ReferenceError: phone is not defined

Tags: node.js, mongoose

What im trying to do is to create clients. From the front end, Im getting requests in an array of more than one client(fullName, phone).
To create them in MongoDB I iterate the req.body.

```
exports.createTrustees = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {


    req.body.forEach( async (user) => {

       const {fullName, phone} = user;
        
        users = await Users.create({
            fullName,
            phone,
        });
    })

  res.status(200, `The user : ${phone} has been registerd!`).json({
    success: true,
    data: users,
  });
});
```

This code it won't work, it shows this error: `ReferenceError: phone is not defined`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which instance of phone is not defined, but I am assuming the one in the `res.status` line.

You are defining the phone variable inside the `req.body.forEach( async (user)` code block - therefore it is only visible (or has scope) within that code block.

You will need to declare a variable `phone` at a higher level e.g.

```
let phone2;

req.body.forEach( async (user) => {

       const {fullName, phone} = user;
       phone2 = phone;
        
        users = await Users.create({
            fullName,
            phone,
        });
    })

 res.status(200, `The user : ${phone2} has been registerd!`).json({
    success: true,
    data: users,
  });
```

Comment: Did this answer help you?